# Docker Swarm - does not start service after daemon restart

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-network

I using Docker Swarm in a test server running about 10 different services. I use docker compose to create the service and connect then to a pre-existing bridge network instead of default overlay network:

```
h2r@test-server:~$ docker network inspect ecommerce-new-bridge 
[{
    "Name": "ecommerce-new-bridge",
    "Id": "pwty628ng11z2px8rz39bdsfx",
    "Created": "2019-01-10T10:46:14.14717554Z",
    "Scope": "swarm",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": []
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": null,
    "Options": null,
    "Labels": null
}]
```

This is one of my docker compose:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    zookeeper:
        image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
        deploy:
            resources:
                limits:
                    memory: 128M
                reservations:
                    memory: 32M
        ports:
            - 2181:2181
        environment:
            - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx128m -Xms32m

    kafka:
        image: wurstmeister/kafka:1.0.0
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper
        deploy:
            resources:
                limits:
                    memory: 256M
                reservations:
                    memory: 128M
        environment:
            KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.1.100
            KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 192.168.1.100:2181
            KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: -Xmx256M -Xms128M
        ports:
            - 9092:9092

    postgresql:
        image: postgres:10.6
        deploy:
            resources:
                limits:
                    memory: 512M
                reservations:
                    memory: 128M
        volumes:
            - /opt/volumes/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=teste
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=teste
            - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
networks:
    default:
        external: true
        name: ecommerce-new-bridge
```

when I create the network and deploy the services the first time, it worked like a charm. However sometimes we need to restart this computer and instead of just start the services, docker is complaining about the network:

```
Rejected 8 seconds ago           "network pwty628ng11z2px8rz39bdsfx exists"   
roh4aroxisobwwqcc144vp9bq   ecommerce_zookeeper.1           wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6@sha256:294d69bb580a614ed3128969b95b5355c480e84704d826cdf73e790b5a6e63fc        test-server         Shutdown
```

Of course that network exists, it was flagged in compose file.
Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm surprised to know it can work with so few memory

Comment: The rejection message seems to tell that such a network exists. Are you sure is it because of the network?

Comment: If you are sure the problem is due to network recreate the same network in attachable mode and try it.

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5745) looks similar. Have you tried running it on boot with the `--force-recreate` flag? that way it will automatically recreate the network upon boot.

Comment: Try to add in docker-compose file in each service ```restart: always```